# Align the form to the center in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am trying to align the form to the center and keep it responsive. I have tried several ways but no success. I am trying to center all the text and the form. I am using Bootstrap v4. I am not sure if that helps.

[image: As you can see that the fr is not aligned to the center]

HTML:

```
<section id="cover">
     <div id="cover-caption">
         <div id="container">
             <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm offset-1">
                 <h1 class="display-3">Welcome to Bootstrap 4</h1>
                 <div class="info-form">
                 <form action="" class="form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Jane Doe">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only">Email</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="jane.doe@example.com">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success ">okay, go!</button>
                </form>
                </div>
                <br>

                <a href="#nav-main" class="btn btn-secondary-outline btn-sm" role="button">&darr;</a>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </section>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body{
 height: 100%;
}

#cover {
  background: #222 url('../img/stars.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
```

}

```
#cover-caption {
  width: 100%;
```

}

Comment: That's not a duplicate as it's relevant only to Bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You need to use the various **Bootstrap 4** centering methods...

- Use `text-center` for inline elements.
- Use `justify-content-center` for flexbox elements (ie; `form-inline`)

https://codeply.com/go/Am5LvvjTxC

Also, to offset the column, the `col-sm-*` must be contained within a `.row`, and the `.row` must be in a container...

```
<section id="cover">
    <div id="cover-caption">
        <div id="container" class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-10 offset-sm-1 text-center">
                    <h1 class="display-3">Welcome to Bootstrap 4</h1>
                    <div class="info-form">
                        <form action="" class="form-inline justify-content-center">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="sr-only">Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Jane Doe">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="sr-only">Email</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="jane.doe@example.com">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success ">okay, go!</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <br>

                    <a href="#nav-main" class="btn btn-secondary-outline btn-sm" role="button">↓</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 23):

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center container ">

    <div class="row ">


        <form action="">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputUserName" class="control-label">Enter UserName</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputUserName" aria-labelledby="emailnotification">
                <small id="emailnotification" class="form-text text-muted">Enter Valid Email Id</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label">Enter Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" aria-labelledby="passwordnotification">

            </div>
        </form>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so. Please [edit] your answer to include such a description.

Comment: Thanks, Finally!

Comment: This answer does not provide `form-inline` element styling as asked in question.

Answer (score 17):

All above answers perfectly gives the solution to center the form using `Bootstrap 4`. However, if someone wants to use out of the box `Bootstrap 4` css classes without help of any additional styles and also **not** wanting to use `flex`, we can do like this.

**A sample form**

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid h-100 bg-light text-dark">
  <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <h1>Form</h1>    
  </div>
  <hr/>
  <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
    <div class="col col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
      <form action="">
        <div class="form-group">
          <select class="form-control">
                    <option>Option 1</option>
                    <option>Option 2</option>
                  </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group text-center">
          <div class="form-check-inline">
            <label class="form-check-label">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio">Option 1
  </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check-inline">
            <label class="form-check-label">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio">Option 2
  </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check-inline">
            <label class="form-check-label">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optradio" disabled>Option 3
  </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col"><button class="col-6 btn btn-secondary btn-sm float-left">Reset</button></div>
              <div class="col"><button class="col-6 btn btn-primary btn-sm float-right">Submit</button></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Link to CodePen**

https://codepen.io/anjanasilva/pen/WgLaGZ

I hope this helps someone. Thank you.

Comment: Yes it helped me! Clearest and simplest answer from my point of view.  One thing I don't understand is what align-items-center is doing here. I tried it without that and didn't see a difference. I think align-items-center has to do with vertical alignment, but I'm just getting started with this stuff.

Comment: Hi @AndyWeinstein. Glad my answer helped you. `align-items-center` vertically centers the element. You are correct on that :) You can find more info through here :- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items . Happy coding :)